# Smooth command not supporting variable colors?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a plot in GNUplot using smooth csplines command. The data file can have many different sections to plot (not constant) and i wold like to use the lc variable option to differentiate them with different color. Am i wrong of is not supporting the lc variable option?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you cannot mix `smooth` and `lc palette` in a single plot command. You could write the smoothed data to an intermediate file with `set table` and then plot this data with lc palette.

Consider the example file `test.txt`:

```
1
3
2
5
4
6
```

Now plot this with:

```
set table 'tmp.txt'
plot 'test.txt' using 0:1 smooth cspline
unset table
```

And then plot the file `tmp.txt` with `lc rgb variable` or similar:

```
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
plot 'test.txt' using 0:1 pt 7 t 'original', \
     'tmp.txt' using 1:2:($2 < 4.2 ? rgb(255,0,0) : rgb(0,255,0)) with lines lc rgb var  t 'smoothed'
```

Result with 4.6.4:

[image]

Note, that this doesn't allow you to use some criteria contained in an additional column of your original data for coloring (say, in the third column of `test.txt`). That would require much more fiddling.